# Sudden problems with External Display on MacBook Pro. DisplayPort shows distortion (lines), HDMI turns on and off every few seconds

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi, apple-silicon, displayport

I have been using this combination of laptop (2021 MacBook Pro M1) and External Display (Mi Curved Gaming Monitor) for several months without issue.

Yesterday while gaming suddenly the screen started distorting, showing lines of color. Essentially any color from below is kind of copied in lines to some of the lines above it. For example if there's a window open halfway on the screen you can clearly see the red, yellow and green lines all the way up to the top of the screen on the same x-position as these buttons. The distortion happens only with DisplayPort.

I have tried different ports (both the USB-C / Lightning ports on the laptop, as well as the DisplayPort ports on my monitor. I also tried a different DisplayPort cable. The issue persists). When I reduce the refresh rate from 144hz to 120hz or 100hz sometimes it briefly appears normal, but after a few seconds the issue returns.

If I use HDMI, the screen appears completely normal, however every few seconds the screen turns black and then normal again. Which makes this solution impractical to work with.

When I connect another laptop the screen shows no issue.

I ran Diagnostics on my MacBook and it did not register any issues. I also updated the OS to Sonoma 14.0 but that didn't fix the issue either.

All of this leads me to believe it's a software / driver issue with the MacBook (or potentially worse: a hardware issue with the MacBook).

What are the steps you recommend to troubleshoot and solve this issue, beyond what I already did?